# Angular-translate update on placeholder

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate

I'm trying to update my language change hardcoded placeholder

so I have 
`<input type="text" placeholder="{{placeholderText}} />`
and in my angular controller
`$scope.placeholderText =filter("translate")("label");`

but when the language is updated the placeholder remains in the original language.

also is there a way to hide the placeholder's `{{placeholderText}}` uppon loading the page, before the translate kicks in.

Answer (score 2):

Just create a ternary statement within your data-binding, using some variable of your choice.

```
placeholder="{{ finishedTranslating ? placeholderText : '' }}"
```

Then within your scope after it translates just flip that `finishedTranslating` variable to true:

```
$scope.finishedTranslating = true;
```

> Note: Ability to use ternary operators was added to data-binding in Angular 1.1.5